# Expecting member declaration in Getter

Tags: kotlin, getter

I'm new to Kotlin and I wrote a very simple class:

```
class Person(age_: Int) {
    var age: Int = age_;
        get() = age - 5
}
```

The line:

```
get() = age
```

Is marked with error:

> Expecting member declaration

How can I write a valid getter?

Comment: You don't need any `get()`. Declaring a `var` declares a mutable property, with a getter and a setter. And since it's initialized by a constructor argument, all you need is `class Person(var age: Int)`

Comment: I know. However, I fixed the code to make the getter method meaningful.

Comment: Semicolon is the error. See how to declare getters/setters: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html Also using `age` in a getter of `age` is likely an error

Comment: And it should be `field - 5`. Otherwise you call your getter in your getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since kotlin automatically generates getters and setters, what you are trying to do is recursive call, good thing that in kotlin this is fixed, in scala you would get recursive calls without any errors.

The correct way to create a getter is the following:

```
class Person(age_: Int) {
    var age: Int = age_
        get() = field - 5
}
```

Comment: Downvoted, because the code doesn't compile with exactly the same error as in the question.